# String sorting with numbers last objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, sorting, compare

I had a good search of SO but couldn't find anything relevant to this problem. I have a custom object class that implements a comparison method for sorting in arrays. This comparison uses the "name" property of the class using NSCaseInsensitiveSearch. The code looks like this:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Forum *)otherObject {
return [self.name compare:otherObject.name options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
}
```

However using NSCaseInsensitiveSearch puts strings with numbers ahead of strings with letters. Is there a way to do the opposite of this so that numbers come after letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just

```
return [self.name compare:otherObject.name options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
```

But do some additional checks, e.g. if self.name starts with a non-numeral and otherObject.name starts with a numeral, then return NSDescendingOrder, and vice versa. IOW, make a numeral > non-numeral. If both are non-numeral or both are numeral, return what you already had.

This little console program explains the principle I mean:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: 
                             @"Adam", @"001", @"Bertha", @"3SeriesBMW", @"Colin",
                             @"Zelda", @"1And1", @"Xaver", @"Kraftwerk", @"TangerineDream",
                             @"5SeriesBMW", @"0ableTypes", nil];

    NSString *sortOrder = @"AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz_0123456789";

    [array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) 
    {
        char char1 = [(NSString *)obj1 characterAtIndex: 0];
        char char2 = [(NSString *)obj2 characterAtIndex: 0];

        int index1;
        for (index1 = 0; index1 < sortOrder.length; index1++)
            if ([sortOrder characterAtIndex: index1] == char1)
                break;

        int index2;
        for (index2 = 0; index2 < sortOrder.length; index2++) 
            if ([sortOrder characterAtIndex: index2] == char2)
                break;

        if (index1 < index2)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (index1 > index2)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return [(NSString *)obj1 compare: obj2 options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }];

    for (NSString *s in array)
        NSLog(@"%@", s);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2011-08-25 14:19:15.538 NumeralSort[5802:707] Adam
2011-08-25 14:19:15.540 NumeralSort[5802:707] Bertha
2011-08-25 14:19:15.540 NumeralSort[5802:707] Colin
2011-08-25 14:19:15.540 NumeralSort[5802:707] Kraftwerk
2011-08-25 14:19:15.541 NumeralSort[5802:707] TangerineDream
2011-08-25 14:19:15.541 NumeralSort[5802:707] Xaver
2011-08-25 14:19:15.541 NumeralSort[5802:707] Zelda
2011-08-25 14:19:15.542 NumeralSort[5802:707] 001
2011-08-25 14:19:15.542 NumeralSort[5802:707] 0ableTypes
2011-08-25 14:19:15.542 NumeralSort[5802:707] 1And1
2011-08-25 14:19:15.543 NumeralSort[5802:707] 3SeriesBMW
2011-08-25 14:19:15.543 NumeralSort[5802:707] 5SeriesBMW
```

This is not exactly the solution, but should get you on your way.

Comment: how can i use this in NSSortDescriptor?

Answer (score 1):

Translate the strings to be compared using a 256-(16-bit)character translate array (assuming you have only standard ASCII characters).  Translate most characters to their own values (or to lower case, to handle the case-insensitive function at the same time), but translate the digits to their values plus some number (say, 0xF000).  Then do the string compare.

If you have characters outside the ASCII range then do the translation a character at a time, copying the character exactly (or lower-casing) for non-digits, and copying the character as the character value plus that large number for digits.